# How to display a single Item from an array of objects - flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

Hello I need help with a question that's a little tricky. I have an array of objects below. These objects are gotten as a results of a get http request I made to an endpoint. The endpoint requires some Ids and those Ids are also returned in the response objects which are: anchorOid, providerOid, and StateOid. So before this response a user will select an anchor, state and provider then it make request to the end point and return the users Stocks object which is the object below. So whatever the user selects before the http request, those are the IDs that would be returned in the response. So my challenge is after getting the response, before I loop through the whole objects and display them using datatable row and column, how can I display just the anchor, State, before iterating over the whole object just to show the user that this is the anchor and state you selected since the anchor and state are the same in all the objects hence the originate from the users selection. How can can do that please?

```
  _getStocksByProviderIdByAnchorIdBySeasonId() async {
    try {
      _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      var _stockService = StockService();
      var result =
          await _stockService.getStocksByProviderIdByAnchorIdBySeasonId(
              _prefs.getInt('providerOid'),
              widget.anchorOid,
              widget.seasonOid,
              widget.stateOid);
      var stocks = await json.decode(result.body);

      _stocks = <Stock>[];
      stocks.forEach((stock) {
        var _stock = Stock();

        _stock.oid = stock['oid'];
        _stock.date = DateTime.parse(stock['date']);
        _stock.anchor = stock['anchor'];
        _stock.state = stock['state'];

        setState(() {
          _stocks.add(_stock);
        });
      });
      print("Stocks");
      print(stocks);

      setState(() {
        data = stocks;
        _isLoading = false;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
      return e.toString();
    }
  }
```

I tried to do this:

```
stocks[0]['anchor]

but its only picking the first index so how do I make the index dynamic I don't know what to do.
```

```
[
  {
    "oid": 3,
    "anchor": "MAIZE ASSOCIATION OF NIGERIA",
    "anchorOid": 1,
    "date": "2021-07-09T14:37:00.403",
    "provider": "ERG Agro Solutions",
    "providerOid": 1,
    "season": "WET SEASON - 2020",
    "seasonOid": 1,
    "stateOid": 1,
    "state": "Abia",
    "stockItems": [],
    "totalStockItems": 0
  },


  {
    "oid": 4,
    "anchor": "MAIZE ASSOCIATION OF NIGERIA",
    "anchorOid": 1,
    "date": "2021-08-09T14:39:00.403",
    "provider": "ERG Agro Solutions",
    "providerOid": 1,
    "season": "WET SEASON - 2020",
    "seasonOid": 1,
    "stateOid": 1,
    "state": "Abia",
    "stockItems": [],
    "totalStockItems": 0
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the **first** method on List like this,

```
void main() {
 List data = [
  {
    "oid": 3,
    "anchor": "MAIZE ASSOCIATION OF NIGERIA",
    "anchorOid": 1,
    "date": "2021-07-09T14:37:00.403",
    "provider": "ERG Agro Solutions",
    "providerOid": 1,
    "season": "WET SEASON - 2020",
    "seasonOid": 1,
    "stateOid": 1,
    "state": "Abia",
    "stockItems": [],
    "totalStockItems": 0
  },


  {
    "oid": 4,
    "anchor": "MAIZE ASSOCIATION OF NIGERIA",
    "anchorOid": 1,
    "date": "2021-08-09T14:39:00.403",
    "provider": "ERG Agro Solutions",
    "providerOid": 1,
    "season": "WET SEASON - 2020",
    "seasonOid": 1,
    "stateOid": 1,
    "state": "Abia",
    "stockItems": [],
    "totalStockItems": 0
  }
];
  print(data.first['anchor']);
}
```

It will always pick the first element of an array.

Comment: ohh ok I see so it doesn't matter the number of array it will just pick the first element. Thanks let me try that and see @Huzaifa Ahmed

Comment: Sure, try and let me know if this solves your problem

Comment: yes it solves the problem sir all I did was to check if isEmpty else it should pick the first element like you showed me thanks very much I appreciate @Huzaifa Ahmed

Comment: Welcome, glad it helps :)